# Delete array row when element don't fit conditions

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array with x rows and 3 columns,having a condition for every column, how can I remove the row when one of the elements does not satisfy the constraints

```py
For example:
5<[:,0]<10
5<[:,1]<10
1<[:,2]<3

[[1, 2, 3 ],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9],
 [9, 9, 1]]

Result should be
[[9,9,1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression below gets only rows matching the conditions.

```
new = arr[(arr >= [5,5,1]).all(1) & (arr < [10,10,3]).all(1)]
```

To get the expected result you need to change the condition to `>=` because 1 is not greater then  1 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def comply(row):
    if row[0] > 5 and row[0] < 10 and row[1] > 5 and row[1] < 10 and row[2] > 1 and row[2] < 3:
        return True
    else:
        return False


result = []
A = [[1, 2, 3 ],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9],
 [9, 9, 1]]

for row in A:
    if comply(row):
        result.append(row)
```